# How to display a DropDownList with the names of the columns in a table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity, html.dropdownlistfor

Good Morning

I have a table called **AGG_TREE** contains 4 following columns:

"**COL_AGG**", "**PARENT_CODE**", "**FACTOR**" and "**DATE_CREATED**"

What I've done: dispayed a DropDownList with the names of the columns and when I select the name of a column I displays its data in a view

This is what I can do :

```
AGG_TREEEntities db = new AGG_TREEEntities();

        var query = (from discs in db.AGG_TREE

                     select ( the names of the columns ??? ).ToList();

        List<string> nameOfMycolumns = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            nameOfMycolumns .Add(item.[the names of the columns ???]);
        }
        ViewBag.NameOfMycolumns  = nameOfMycolumns ;
        return View();
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: and what is the problem actually?

Comment: Good morning, I want to display (populate) dynamically a DropDownList with the names of my clonnes

Comment: can you provide some code and point out what exactly your problem is?

Comment: I do not have a code, I 'm starting in progrmmation , I want a code that displays a drop-down list with table column names and when I select a table name , I displays its data in a view

Comment: but you will have to show at least some kind of effort... no one here will just write code for you.